# Is it possible to find that $f(0) = 1$ with the only hypothesis $f(x) = f'(x)$?

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, exponential-function

I often read in maths books when attemting to find to find the function which has the property $f(x) = f'(x)$, that by assumption  $f(0) = 1$.

Is there a way to find this result $f(0) = 1$, with the only hypothesis that $f(x) = f'(x)$ ?

Thank you for your concern.

Comment: What about $f(x) = 15 e^x$?

Comment: If $f$ satisfies $f' = f$ then any constant multiple of $f$ satisfies the same equation. That is a general property of “linear differential equations.” With $f(0) = 1$ it becomes an “initial value problem” which makes the solution unique.

Comment: Can you please give precise quote(s) and/or reference(s) of what you "often read in maths books"?

Comment: @AnneBauval "Cours de mathématiques générales" from René Garnier (french) for exemple

Comment: @Martin R
Can you expose it explicitly in a response ?

Comment: Thank you for the reference. What is his exact sentence? (or a photo of that page). Sorry for insisting but it is because I suspect a misinterpretation.

Comment: @AnneBauval

[René Garnier Talking about the way to search such a function that satisfies $f' = f$.]

Translated from french : "Thus, it exists an infinity of functions similar to their dervatives [...]. We will precise the problem assuming that the function to determinate $f(x)$ verifies the condition : $f(0) = 1$"

Comment: Excellent! This is what I expected. So you misinterpreted Garnier : he says the same as Martin R. He does not *derive* $f(0)=1$ from $f'=f$. It is an *additional assumption*, so that the solution becomes unique.